# javascript - i can only call the click function a button from console. buttons not clicking

Tags: javascript, click, frontend, zooming, lightbox

recently i hired a lady from a website to help me with a specific design (who I can't find anymore). i took that design and worked on the server side and finished my web app. the client requested to have a ligthbox zoom option on the images. I have used many methods but it seems that I can't fire the click event from the front-end, I can only use the "image.click()" method from the browser console. this is an html code snippet:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-6" style="text-align: center; margin: auto;">
<img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" style="cursor: pointer;"src="img-src">
</div>
</div>
<div id="lightbox" class="lightbox"><img src=""></div>
```

i want to do the zoom effect on multiple images

```
Array.from($('.img-fluid')).forEach(image => {
$(image).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#lightbox img').attr('src', $(image).attr('src'))
        $('#lightbox').toggle()
    });
})
```

the only way this works is when I use the browser console with a click method.

any suggestions on the reason ?

Comment: the click callback is not firing when i click. only from the console

Comment: this is unclear, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What do you want to know? I gave what ever I saw related. Let me know if there is something specific is needed

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click):

> The `HTMLElement.click()` method simulates a mouse click on an element.

So, if you want to fire the event when the user clicks on the image, the proper way is to use [onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) method instead.

> The `click` event is raised when the user clicks on an element. It fires after the mousedown and mouseup events, in that order.

Or you can add a [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), it depends on your needs.

Comment: that what the jquery click also does. i used the addEventListener before that  and still the same issue